# Graphing divergence of a 3D vector field

Tags: matlab, vector-fields

I want to be able to compute and graph the divergence of a three dimensional vector field. I have tried
the following and the resulting graph is as attached.

```
clc
syms x y z
f = input("Enter the 3D vector function as [f1, f2, f3]");
div(x, y, z) = divergence(f, [x, y, z]);
p(x, y, z) = f(1); q(x, y, z) = f(2); r(x, y, z) = f(3);
x = linspace(-4, 4, 20); y = x; z = x;
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);
U = p(X, Y, Z); V = q(X, Y, Z); W = r(X, Y, Z);
hold on
quiver3(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, 1.5);
axis on
hold off
title("Vector Field of F(x, y, z) = [f1, f2, f3]");
```

and the figure output for $(x, 2y^2, 3z^3)$ -

[image]

Now obviously I would like for the figure to be represented in 3D, and I did use `quiver3` for the purpose.

Surely there's something iffy with my code. An elaborate explanation about my mistakes here would be much appreciated.

I must state that I copied the code from what was taught to us for computing the divergence of 2D functions and simply went about making changes to accommodate the third variable. Also, I'm a total noob at MATLAB. My professor doesn't help my situation. Their forums have been helpful in understanding.

Comment: Consider asking this question in https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The problem is the default display settings do not seem to want to give a 3-d view. I am not immediately sure how to fix this, and as suggested, stack overflow is likely a better option. However while the figure is displayed, try rotating by first clicking the cube with an arrow around it in the upper right area of the figure.

Comment: Thanks @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I shall do that. I actually arrived from there thinking the opposite that matlab professionals would be lurking around here. Thanks again

Comment: [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180303-how-to-set-the-3d-rotation-of-a-matlab-graph-using-code) might help your problem as matlab is actually plotting a 3-d vector field, but display settings show a 2-d vector field

Comment: The MathWorks page on [quiver3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) seems to suggest that the command `axis equal` will fix the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $f({\bf x}) = (x, 2 y^2, 3 z^3)$ so $\nabla f({\bf x}) = (1, 4 y, 9 z^2)$.

Here is a plot of the divergence (as a scalar color) atop the vector function (rendered in *Mathematica*):

[image]

Comment: Looks neat! Although I would love for you to be able to explain what is going wrong in my code.

Comment: I work in *Mathematica*, which I prefer to *Matlab*.  Note that this is a MATHEMATICS site, not a programming or coding site, so you'll have more luck elsewhere.

Comment: Got it. I've taken this to StackOverflow.  Thank you so much for your troubles. I now know what to expect from this program.